# create a class for the settings page in spritekit

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2

i designed a layout for a settings window to pop out with buttons and what not in it, and i want to avoid spagetti code by creating a seperate class for the settings menu. I'm not quite sure how to do this. I so far tried creating a class in swift that is of type sknode, but don't know where to go from there

```
class menu:SKNode {
    let button = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"button") 
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(){
        super.init()
         var fixedSize = self.frame.width/11
    background.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.width-fixedSize, self.frame.size.height-fixedSize)
    background.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2)
    self.addChild(background)
    }
}


 //In the main method i said let settings = menu()  self.addChild(settings)   background sprite doesn't show
```

Comment: You can't use menu that way - you would just use `addChild` (or `self.addChild`).

Also you should be more detailed in your question. what is the error you're getting?

Comment: i updated the code description ^^. The comment at the bottom of the code explains it better then i can here.

Answer (score 1):

You want a SKNode called Menu that will hold all the buttons, images, etc. You have to create a SKNode. Every thing you want the menu to have, you have to add it as a child to the Menu (so it would be `self.addChild(button)` from the Menu class).

Then, in your scene class you have to create a menu object and add it as a child `self.addChild(menu)`.

You can use the Menu class to control the touch for the Menu buttons implementing `touchesBegan` method for example, and setting `userInteractionEnabled` to `true`, in this way you will have decoupled from the scene all the menu UI and logic.

Comment: would i declare the buttons and set there sizes and positions within the menu class as well?

Comment: also for some reason nothing shows up when i add a sprite to the class and i self.addchild() the class object in the touches began method. I update the code description ^^^ the comment at the bottom of the code explains everything